# Add new API to Magento module

Tags: magento2, module, customer, di

I would like to add new API to 
Magento Customer module -> AccountManagementInterface.

I have created my custom module but I don't know how should my `di.xml` be written?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add below code in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface"
                type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Myaccountmanagement" />
</config>
```

Add your vendor and modulename in above code

Using above code you can implement `AccountManagementInterface` in your module which is defined in `di.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You should not extend Interfaces of other modules.
Just add new calls in your.